# I want to display multiple data in database with multiple login in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

but my data is display only one. can you help me sir ? How i can display all data.

Public function tampiluserhotspot(){

```
    $datas = Mikrotik::all();

   foreach($datas as $data) {
        
        $client = new Client([
            'host' => $data->iprouter,
            'user' => $data->username,
            'pass' => $data->password
        ]);


    $query = collect($client->query('/ip/hotspot/user/print')->read());
    $query1 = collect($client->query('/ip/hotspot/user/profile/print')->read());

    $response = $query;
    $response2 = $query1;

   }

    return  view('admin.hotspot',[
        "datauser" => $response,
        "datauserprofile" => $response2
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use "merge" function to combine multiple collections.declare a collection before "foreach" and use "merge" to add collections that you fetch in "foreach" loop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: oke sir i try again